# Frequently used methods to estimate copula of discrete random variable in high dimension

Tags: random-variables, poisson-distribution, copula

I am new to the estimation of copula with discrete marginal distributions. For example, I have the data of 30 discrete random count variables from $X_1$ to $X_{30}$, some $X_j$ has Poisson distribution, some $X_j$ has Negative Binomial distribution. I want to estimate a copula to model the joint distribution of these 30 random variables.

I am rather in the direction of nowhere because I have read a lot of articles, the authors proposes some methods like Bayesian Data Augmentation but I don't understand this method, it seems to be beyond my knowledge so I would like to ask for your opinion to have a starting point.

Would you please suggest me some good methods in your point of view to do so and if possible, an article or an example of a R package to implement the method.

Thank you very much for your help!